# PHP - Include fails at times

Tags: php, include

I have my code:

> include("top.php");
>
> ```
> /*
>
> */
> include("bottom.php");
> ```

Sometimes the bottom.php file is not included and the page looks really awkward. This happens on any page after the 500 Internal Server error. However this does also happen at random times.

The page fully loads after a refresh or two.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem as it is very annoying.

Thank You

Comment: After what 500 error?

Comment: it sounds that you have already some functions declared on "bottom.php" and on "top.php"

Comment: im sure that you have some error on your files

Comment: whene this happends it is that variables used can not be accepted by the php whene it does not happend variables can be accepted by the php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
include_once("top.php");
include_once("bottom.php");
```

Comment: Works :)! Is there a way I can update all the 65 files automatically instead of changing each one?

Comment: i'm glad, so first of all mark my post as a solution. Now i'm going to try to understand what you mean with your question. For that please provide sample code and explain what you want to do, because tour original post does not talk about updating files

Comment: @K3rnel31: i've just posted my solution before you, they are the same because it is the solution...but here is not the challenge : the goal is to help others, no ?

Comment: I figured the problem that was left :) Marked as answered!

Comment: thanks man ! and what about your files update ? maybe you should start a new topic for that

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once("top.php");
include_once("bottom.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your scripts stops running before the execution of `include("bottom.php");`. Check the lines above that and make sure to add arguments to `die()` commands to identify the problem.